# z-index doesn't put dropdown HTML on top

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, z-index, transparency

I need help getting dropdown menu expanding on top. I put `z-index` on it, yet for some reason I'd like to understand it blends with the rest. The dropdown expands when one types in "Enter your region" [on my site 33hotels.com](http://33hotels.parseapp.com/#/search).

I am sorry to post no code but the main problem is I don't know which part of it is responsible for this effect.

Thanks!

EDIT.
Turned out that setting `position: absolute` instead `fixed` solved the problem! Also strangely it only was a problem in Chrome and Safari but not Firefox!

Comment: If possible then give position absolute

Comment: if you want your drop down to be top give z-index value higher than other

Comment: @ketan Surpisingly it worked when I replaced fixed by absolute! Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add z-index property to #location-search element. You may just set it to 1.

```
#location-search {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 45px;
    margin: 0 5px;
}
```

Remember, that z-index only works for a fraternal elements - those, who have the same parent. It means, if you have two non-static positioned elements in same parent you can use z-index to place them inside their parent. But as long as they have different parents - you can only rule with their parents z-indecies.

```
<div id="Wrapper">
    <div id="Test1">blue</div>
    <div id="Test2">red</div>
</div>

div { position: absolute; }
#Test1 { background: blue; z-index: 10; }
#Test2 { background: red; z-index: 9; }
/* blue is over red, though declared earlier */
```

But

```
<div id="Wrapper">
    <div id="InnerWrapper">
        <div id="Test1">blue</div>
    </div>
    <div id="Test2">red</div>
</div>

div { position: absolute; }
#InnerWrapper { z-index: 10; }
#Test1 { background: blue; z-index: 15; }
#Test2 { background: red; z-index: 11; }
/* red is over blue, for blue's wrapper has no z-index or lower */
```

Comment: I forgot to declare z-index for the inner wrapper element, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Set `z-index` to `-1` in this css, because your `dropdown-menu` class is having `-z-index` of `1000` so you need to set your main content should get behind the autocomplete dropdown.

```
#row-content {
  position: fixed;
  top: 85px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: Why `-1`? Isn't default setting (no `z-index`) already places it below `1000`?

Answer (score 0):

Also remember to set element positions, because z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed).